# How to understand how many dB are at different points on the track?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

How to understand how many dB Decibels are at different points on the track?

I need to understand how much I need to lower the thunder (Decibel) to fit into the standard from -10 to -14 dB.
[image]

Comment: I think this is not the right place for these questions. Yes, Blender can import audio files, but it's far from being an audio editor. You should prepare the audio tracks in dedicated software.

Comment: Just think of the following: the track you posted here is a stereo audiotrack. But Blender uses only one slot for the file so there is a mono waveform displayed - which cannot actually be the correct display for this file. If you're using a file where left and right are much more different from each other you'd see Blender shows an averaged waveform of both channels. So if an audio software would show -6 dB for the left and -16 dB for the right channel in a certain place, then Blender would display this as -11 dB, which would be in your desired range although the left channel is much louder.

Comment: You can either use this add-on which will give you a VU meter: https://github.com/snuq/VSEQF or use this add-on to pipe audio between the VSE and Audacity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f61Zvb8AipA or use this add-on to export the audio to DAW: https://github.com/snuq/Quick-EDL-Exporter

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I think that is a pretty decent answer to this question right there, actually explaining what the waveform values mean. Would you post that as an answer? Feel free to ping me if you do

Comment: @tintwotin I start use VU meter from github.com/snuq/VSEQF. It really useful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I start using this addon - [VSE Quick Functions Addon](https://github.com/snuq/VSEQF). it has VU meter and This solved my problem in order to adjust the volume to the values I needed and see the volume in dB.
Thank you, @tintwotin, for the advice to use this addon.

[image]